# Variance of a Joint Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint density:

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
2-x-y,& 0<x,y<1\\
0,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

My question is to find $\operatorname{Var}(X)$. I have tried taking the marginal density so that I can calculate the expected values, but I'm not sure how to deal with the infinities in the limits. I usually deal with infinities when there is an euler function, but I'm not sure how to approach it here. Thanks in advance.

When I arrive at the evaluation of $2y - xy - \frac12 y^2$ from $-\infty$ to $1$, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The joint density function has not been described well.  What values of $x,y$ are permitted?  What does "if $0$" mean in this context?  Can you explain what "infinities" you encountered?

Comment: Sorry the formating messed up.

Comment: For how to format mathematics using LaTeX and MathJax on this site, see this meta post, [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I want to bring out and emphasize for clarity.  Anytime x or y is outside the square, $[-1, 1] \times [-1, 1], f = 0$  The integral of zero is zero.  So frequently in this and related questions we only consider the domain where $f$ is nonzero.

Comment: The notation $0<x, y<1$ is an abbreviation, possibly oversimplified to the point of confusion for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$

Answer (score 2):

I do your homework just because I would like you to see how to use MathJax.

**EDITED:**

To answer your question asked in a comment below:

Reason (a): You said so: " 0 < x, y < 1." What else is that supposed to mean?

Reason (b): Also, the double integral over the domain of the joint distribution has to equal $1$. It does:

$$\iint_{[0,1]\times[0,1]} (2-x-y)\ dy\ dx=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^1(2-x-y)\ dy \right]dx=\int_0^1(2-x-\frac{1}{2})\ dx=\left[2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x\right]_0^1=2-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=1.$$

Reason (c): I did not want to guess, I used what I was told and looked reasonable...

**The original answer:**

The joint density is defined as follows:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}2-x-y,&\text{ if }0\le  x\le 1 \text{ and }0\le  y\le 1\\
0,& \text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

So, there is no $\infty$ anywhere.

For the marginal density of $X$ we have, for $0\le  x\le 1$,
$$f_X(x)=\int_0^1f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int_0^1(2-x-y)dy=\left[2y-xy-\frac{1}{2}y^2 \right]_0^1=2-x-\frac{1}{2},$$
and $0$ otherwise.
Now, the expectation of $X$ and of $X^2$ are, by definition,
$$E[X]=\int_0^1 xf_X(x)=\int_0^1 2x-x^2-\frac{1}{2}xdx=\left[x^2-\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^2\right]_0^1=\frac{5}{12},$$
$$E[X^2]=\int_0^1 x^2f_X(x)=\int_0^12x^2-x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^2 dx=\left[\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^4-\frac{1}{6}x^3\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{4}.$$
The variance is then
$$\sigma^2=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=\frac{1}{9}.$$

Comment: How can you just assume those limits?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I might be missing some crucial property, but doesn't that mean that x goes from 0 to infinity, and likewise with y (- infinity to 1)?

Comment: The most important two properties of a density function are (1) its integral over the whole plane equals $1$. (2) The integral of the joint density, over every possible (measurable) planar sets, is positive. These two properties imply my (your) choice.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2442317  $0 < x,y < 1$ is read as "both $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $1$".  That is: $0 < x < 1$ and $0< y< 1$.  Not as: $0< x$ and $y< 1$.